# Activate Visual Web Part Package in Share Point 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have created a new project of SharePoint 2010 --> Visual Web part,
seleted it as form solution. and it created the web part.

I just edited it with Hello World! for confirmation and deployed it using VS, and successfully added to page.

problem, arrises when i activated the same package after uploaded it from site actions--> site settings --> galleries --> Solutions 
-- > upload new solution --> activate it.

**error came:**

This solution contains invalid markup or elements that cannot be deployed as part of a sandboxed solution. Solution manifest for solution 'GUID' failed validation, file manifest.xml, line 14, character 4: The element 'Solution' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/' has invalid child element 'TemplateFiles' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/'. List of possible elements expected: 'FeatureManifests, ActivationDependencies' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/'

I don't know why VS didn't get this error while its deployment or i am missing some thing while my deployment.

any idea?

Comment: You probably need to use the 'sandboxed' config then.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your visual web part as sand boxed solution your problem will be resolved

Comment: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Visual-Web-Parts-in-SharePoint-2010-cannot-be-Sandboxed.aspx

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/78391773-b671-4607-8447-e7d9fdc3162c